# How can I see if the request path matched but Accept did not in a catch-all handler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Normally spring will return a 404 response for a request mapping where the path did not match, and return a 406 if the path did match but the "Accept" header did not match.

I have a default controller which acts as a "catch-all" which handles rest faults by returning faults in the `Accept`ed format. Controller is of the form:

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController {
    @RequestMapping("/**")
    public void unmappedRequest(HtpServletRequest req) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Trouble is if I do get a match here, I can't tell if it matched elsewhere. I want to return the correct error to the client and tell them the `Accept`able types they may retry with. Currently all I can do is throw a general `ResourceNotFound` exception.

Is this something I can do in a `@Controller` or am I going to need to resort to writing some sort of filter chain for this?

FWIW I'm using the [ReST exception handling pattern demonstrated by Stormpath](http://www.stormpath.com/blog/spring-mvc-rest-exception-handling-best-practices-part-2)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a catch all controller is good way to handle "unmapped urls" at all.

I would suggest implementing a custom implementation of AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver, and not relying on the Default implementation provided by Spring. The doResolveException can be extended to do almost anything you want with the request and response.

If you want this custom ExceptionResolver to apply only to specific controllers (REST controllers), you can set mappedHandlerClasses on the exception resolver with a list of controllers you want. Also, you can set the order of the custom exception resolver such that it sits before the default resolver.

If you think I'm off topic here, please let me know.